# new Date(..).getTime() is not equal to moment(..).valueOf() in momentJS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`new Date(..).getTime()` should return a timestamp in milliseconds. According to the [documentation of momentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/) the expression `moment(..).valueOf()` should do the same *(return timestamp in milliseconds for a given date)*.

I checked with the following example data:

```
var timeStampDate = new Date("2015-03-25").getTime(); //timestamp in milliseconds?
> 1427241600000
var timeStampMoment = moment("03-25-2015", "MMDDYYYY").valueOf(); //timestamp in milliseconds?
> 1427238000000
```

As you can see the results were not the same.

Now I'm searching for a function in **momentJS** that returns to me the exact same data that the expression `new Date(..).getTime()`.

Comment: This doesn't fix your issue, but in general it's a good idea to have the format string match the input format: `moment("03-25-2015", "MM-DD-YYYY")`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Date constructor [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> The UTC time zone is used to interpret arguments in ISO 8601 format
>   that do not contain time zone information

moment constructor [doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> Unless you specify a timezone offset, parsing a string will create a date in the current timezone

so specifying the timezone in the moment constructor results in the same behavior as Date:

```
var timeStampMoment = moment("03-25-2015 +0000", "MM-DD-YYYY Z").valueOf(); //> 1427241600000
```

Answer (score 7):

When you pass in the same value to Date and moment (at least in Chrome a few years on), you get the same value from both values.

```
new Date("2015-03-25").getTime()
1427241600000
moment("03-25-2015", "MMDDYYYY").valueOf()
1427259600000
new Date("03-25-2015").getTime()
1427259600000
```

What you actually hit was just a different guess of the Date format in [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: appreciated the explanation